# Where do I perform circuit simulation and testing of the circuit schematic before actual implementation?

Tags: simulation

[image]

I am new in circuit simulation.In the given circuit obtained from [TI'S WEBENCH](https://webench.ti.com/webench5/power/webench5.cgi?origin=ti_panel&lang_chosen=en_US&VinMin=100.0&VinMax=120.0&O1V=5.0&O1I=2.5&op_TA=40), DC to DC buck conversion (110V to 5V) using flyback opto-coupler feedback topology is used. I want to perform circuit simulation and testing of the circuit schematic before actual implementation.

But which is best free software available on internet where I can do circuit simulation testing with Texas instruments [UCC28C40 IC](http://www.ti.com/product/UCC28C40) (PWM  controller) included in its component list?

Comment: LTspice + find a .subcrct for that UCC28C40 or susbtiute a different controller.

Comment: Probably only TINA TI will have UCC28C40 in its component list and even that might not have it off the bat. I'd go with @winny solution.

Comment: @Arsenal The crazy Russians have UC1843 in the library here: http://ltwiki.org/?title=Components_Library_and_Circuits. It might be close enough. There is Webench too.

Comment: @winny Well you can just use the models supplied by [TI](http://www.ti.com/product/UCC28C40/toolssoftware) directly... But sometimes they won't work in LTSpice sadly.

Comment: @Arsenal I have installed LTspice. it looks like [this](http://postimg.org/image/9nocgeoh7/) .Then how do I add UCC28c40 component in it.I am not finding any option regarding it

Comment: The format of this website is too limited to give you a complete introduction of LTSpice and the features you need to simulate your rather complex circuit. Starting points: [Getting started guide](http://cds.linear.com/docs/en/software-and-simulation/LTspiceGettingStartedGuide.pdf), [Hotkeys](http://cds.linear.com/docs/en/software-and-simulation/LTspiceIV_flyer.pdf), [Importing a third party model](http://www.linear.com/solutions/4678). And I highly recommend you use the help and read it carefully, it contains lots of useful information.

Comment: @user3559780 actually if you would figure out how this site works you would have found the spice simulator built into the site. Its int the question box

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will want to use TI's model in spice simulation http://www.farnell.com/simulation/1746635.zip?_ga=1.248798085.341376100.1470941132

Comment: I have downloaded free OrCAD 16.6 Lite Software (Capture / PSpice) in my PC. But when I try to add the above orcad file from your zip folder it gives error as "Lite edition is limited to 60 or less components and 75 or less nets. Can not netlist " . So what should I do now?

Comment: @user3559780 Install LTspice.

Comment: @winny I have installed LTspice. it looks like [this](http://postimg.org/image/9nocgeoh7/) .Then how do I add UCC28c40 component in it.I am not finding any option regarding it

Comment: Follow this guide: http://www.zen22142.zen.co.uk/ltspice/addnewparts.htm

Answer (score 2):

[Circuitlab](https://www.circuitlab.com/) is a very nice online cloud based simulator but if you have some money to spend I highly recommend [Everycircuit](http://everycircuit.com/). It is like circuitlab but with **more features**.

You can see the current flow in real time and you can also adjust the parameters in real time. It is very intuitive !

But you wont find the UCC28C40 on those 2 tools. You can try to find or make a substitute of the UCC28C40.

[LTSpice](http://www.linear.com/designtools/software/) is a desktop based circuit simulator that is very popular. It has not the UCC28C40 in his default component list but there is a chance that you can find a tirth party model of UCC28C40 free to download.  <s>If I'm correct (not sure): the file extension of third party components of LTSpice are ".SUBCKT".</s>

Thank you *@Arsenal* for correcting me, here is his post: "LTSpice doesn't care much about the file extension of the circuit. You have to use the spice directive .libor .include to get it into your simulation. The .subckt defines a new subcircuit."

Screenshot of everycircuit:
[image: everycircuit]

Comment: LTSpice doesn't care much about the file extension of the circuit. You have to use the spice directive `.lib`or `.include` to get it into your simulation. The `.subckt` defines a new subcircuit.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you obtained the schematic directly from TI's WEBENCH. If your aim is **not** putting a voltmeter/oscilloscope/ammeter etc. then WEBENCH itself is sufficient for you. At the top of WEBENCH window you can find "Op Vals", "Schematic", "Charts" etc. They're all simulation-related tools.

EDIT: There's a spice-based simulation software called TINA-TI (http://www.ti.com/tool/tina-ti) but I'm not sure if its library contents and Flyback simulation capabilities can meet your expectations.

Comment: No, there isn't. You're a civil and you're not from Sudan, North Korea, Iran or Syria. I've just downloaded it with no problems.

Comment: I have downloaded and installed the TINA-TI software. I am trying to find UCC28C40 for inserting into the schematic but I am not findinding it anywhere. Could you help me? the window is [this](http://postimg.org/image/r28koolm3/)

Comment: Sorry, I've no idea about how to use the software. I've downloaded (to see if there's a problem about the government related forms etc) but not installed. As I said before, I'm not sure if it can meet your expectations. Maybe you should first try by clicking on "SMPS".